# Apache configuration resulting in recursive /index.html

Tags: apache-2.2, puppet

I'm using puppet to configure Apache, and have a problem. I'm trying to serve a simple front page, with links to 2 subpages for Kibana and Uchiwa. I'm trying to use `http://server/logging` for kibana, and `http://server/monitor` as a redirect to Uchiwa. So far, the `/monitor` URL works fine, redirecting nicely.

The `/logging` URL ends up point me at `http://server/monitor/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/...` etc.

The resulting config that Puppet generates looks like that pasted below: if someone can spot the problem in that, I can fix the Puppet setup!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName testnode.local.net

  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/frontpage/"
  AliasMatch /logging "/usr/share/kibana/"

  <Directory "/var/www/html/frontpage/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/testnode.local.net_error.log"
  ServerSignature Off
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/testnode.local.net_access.log" combined

  Redirect permanent /monitor http://testnode.local.net:3000/

  ServerAlias testnode
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come back to this after lunch, and found the problem. I've since tweaked my config slightly to add a `Directory` block for the other folder (`/kibana`), but I think the key change was this:

```
Alias /logging "/usr/share/kibana/"
```

Changing the `AliasMatch` to `Alias`!

Hope this helps future Googlers.